# Label enabled issue

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I set Label component enabled property to "false", it still can interactive,

```
<mx:Label text="testEnable" click="handleEnable()" enabled="false"/>
```

when I click the label, the handleEnable() can always be invoked, I want Label behaves like Button component(if set Button enabled, user can't interactive with it), so how can I do?

Comment: Show some code!  What is the handleEnable() function?  Is it something you created?  Does it run in response to an event, or are you running it manually?

Comment: handleEnable() is handler of click event,<mx:Label click="handleEnable()"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the enabled property to false, some components still respond to mouse interactions such as mouseOver. As a result, to fully disable UIComponents, you should also set the value of the *mouseEnabled* property to false.

Comment: Wouldn't label.mousechildren = false; disable UIComponents do this better?